# How to create a sql batch/job to update a table once a day

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

i am new in SQL, i am trying to update a table once a day by creating a batch, can anybody please guide me through this. I will really appreciate any help.

This is what i'm trying to accomplish:

```
  update Products 
  Set DaysLeft =(
          SELECT DATEDIFF(day, getDate(), ExpirationDate) from Products
   )
```

Comment: What version of SQL? SQL Server? Please do some research on SQL Agent jobs

Comment: How about skipping the job and using a view with `DaysLeft` as a computed column?

Comment: I added the SQL Azure tag for you. Please next time add it when you ask the question originally.

Comment: Glen, something like this?: ALTER TABLE Products
ADD daysLeft as (DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), ExpirationDate)

Comment: According to MS: "Microsoft Azure SQL Database does not support SQL Server Agent or jobs. You can, however, run SQL Server Agent on your on-premise SQL Server and connect to Microsoft Azure SQL Database.". They are suggesting you use an external scheduler (not on Azure) to connect and run that statement

Comment: Nick, do you think the computed Column can work for me? ALTER TABLE Products ADD daysLeft as (DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), ExpirationDate))

Comment: Carlos, google for sql views. Looking at something like this: `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW Products_vw AS  SELECT product_id, product_name, DATEDIFF(day, getDate(), ExpirationDate) AS DaysLeft
    FROM Products;` Then query the view rather than the underlying table `SELECT * FROM Products_vw;`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a procedure to update a table and then u can create a job calling that procedure , you can keep the frequency of the job everyday at whatever time you want to set .

for job creation you can use DBMS_JOB

Thanks,
Abhimpi

Comment: Abhimpi, thank you for the response. I am using SQL Azure how can i create the job? thank you in advance!

Comment: I was talking about Oracle pl/sql . For SQL Azure i have to check . I can share you the details for Oracle if you want , you can check for SQL azure ... there is another solution also , you can call your update statement through ksh and call it through autosys job

Answer (score 1):

This is what I tried and it works.

```
  ALTER TABLE Offer 
  ADD daysLeft as (DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(),ExpirationDate ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Azure Automation service to schedule workflows that run on a daily basis in Azure.  These workflows can contain any Powershell commands, including commands invoking SQL statements.  A good example of using Azure Automation with Azure SQL is covered in this blog: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/06/26/azure-automation-your-sql-agent-in-the-cloud/